# Solving a symmetric equation involving three variables a,b and c

Tags: systems-of-equations, algebraic-equations

Solve : $$\frac{x+a^2}{a+b}+\frac{x+b^2}{b+c}+\frac{x+c^2}{c+a}=2(a+b+c)$$
I am trying to find a simple technique to solve this equation as there is a pattern in the equation, but I could not do. Any help will be highly appreciated.

My attempt: I tried the long method by separating all $x$ terms on the Left Hand Side and the other terms on the Right Hand Side, but even that is becoming too big. Please suggest an appropriate method.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ integers?

Comment: Do you know the source for this interesting equation? That may suggest a solution technique.

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$\frac{x+a^2}{a+b}+\frac{x+b^2}{b+c}+\frac{x+c^2}{c+a} = 2(a+b+c) = (c+a) + (a+b) + (b+c)$$
$$\frac{x+a^2}{a+b}+\frac{x+b^2}{b+c}+\frac{x+c^2}{c+a} = \frac{(a+b)(c+a)}{a+b}+\frac{(a+b)(b+c)}{b+c}+\frac{(b+c)(c+a)}{c+a}$$
$$=  \frac{a^2+(ab+bc+ca)}{a+b}+\frac{b^2+(ab+bc+ca)}{b+c}+\frac{c^2+(ab+bc+ca)}{c+a}$$
Now, we can see that $x=ab+bc+ca$ is one solution.

Let $x'$ be another solution such that $x'=x+d$. Then, substituting it in the equation, we have:
$$ \frac{d}{a+b}+\frac{d}{b+c}+\frac{d}{c+a} = 0 $$ which implies:
$$ \frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a} = 0 $$
However, the above need not be true for all $(a,b,c)$

Hence, we can conclude that the only solution is $x=ab+bc+ca$ unless $a^2+b^2+c^2+3ab+3bc+3ca = 0$ where any $x$ would work.

Note that you can find values $c$ for constants $a$ and $b$ to satisfy the above special criteria using quadratic equations. You can try it out!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding and factoring immediately gives
$$
x = ab+ac+ bc.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\frac{x+a^2}{a+b}+\frac{x+b^2}{b+c}+\frac{x+c^2}{c+a}&=2(a+b+c)\\
\frac{x}{a+b}+\frac{a^2}{a+b}+\frac{x}{b+c}+\frac{b^2}{b+c}+\frac{x}{c+a}+\frac{c^2}{c+a}&=2(a+b+c)\\
x(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a})&=\frac{2a(a+b)-a^2}{a+b}+\frac{2b(b+c)-b^2}{b+c}+\frac{2c(c+a)-c^2}{c+a}\\
x\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+3ab+3ac+3b}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\right)&=\frac{2a(a+b)-a^2}{a+b}+\frac{2b(b+c)-b^2}{b+c}+\frac{2c(c+a)-c^2}{c+a}
\end{align}
$$
I think this is nice enough to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sum_{cyc}$ be cyclic sums over the 3 variables $a,b,c$. The equation at hand can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{x+a^2}{a+b} = 2\sum_{cyc}a$$

One approach to simplify this expression is convert it to cyclic sums that involve only one variable. Notice

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+b^2}{a+b} = \sum_{cyc}\frac{(x+a^2)+(b^2-a^2)}{a+b} =\sum_{cyc}\left[\frac{x+a^2}{a+b} + (b-a)\right] = \sum_{cyc} \frac{x+a^2}{a+b}$$
We can rewrite the equation as

$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{2x + a^2 + b^2}{a + b} = 4\sum_{cyc} a$$

Let $\lambda = \sum_{cyc} a$ and $\mu = 2x + \sum_{cyc} a^2 - \lambda^2$, above equation becomes

$$\begin{align} &
\sum_{cyc} \frac{\mu + \lambda^2 - c^2}{\lambda - c}
= \sum_{cyc} \left[\frac{\mu}{\lambda - c} + (\lambda + c)\right] = 4\lambda\\
\implies &
\mu \sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\lambda - c} = 4\lambda - (3\lambda + \sum_{cyc} c ) = 0\\
\implies &
2x + \sum_{cyc} a^2 - \lambda^2 = \mu = 0\\
\implies &
x = \frac12\left[\left(\sum_{cyc} a\right)^2 - \sum_{cyc} a^2 \right]
= ab+bc+ca
\end{align}
$$